# Python: replace all characters in between two symbols that occur multiple times in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, replace

So I have a URL for a video file, and there is a simple hack I can do to get the audio file where I need to edit the string in a certain way.

Here is the starting string:

`https://v.redd.it/jvjih3f894b61/DASH_1080.mp4?source=fallback`

I need replace the resolution `DASH_1080` to `DASH_audio` and I figured I could just replace everything between the `_` after `DASH` and the `.` before `.mp4` but there are multiple occurrences of `.` so using `string.partition` would not work.

The URL should look like this:

`https://v.redd.it/jvjih3f894b61/DASH_audio.mp4?source=fallback`

How could I do this, preferably without regex but I understand it might be the only way.

Thank you.

Comment: will it always be `DASH_1080` ?

Comment: Why without a regex?

Comment: no it could be varying resolutions. Some include `DASH_720`, `DASH_480`, and `DASH_240`. `DASH_` will always be there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'https://v.redd.it/jvjih3f894b61/DASH_1080.mp4?source=fallback'
>>> re.sub('DASH_\d+', 'DASH_audio', s)
'https://v.redd.it/jvjih3f894b61/DASH_audio.mp4?source=fallback'
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean.. it's ugly and a regex is better but it'll likely work...

```
str = "https://v.redd.it/jvjih3f894b61/DASH_1080.mp4?source=fallback"
str_split = str.split("DASH_")
end_str = str_split[1].split(".")
str = str_split[0] + "DASH_audio." + ".".join(end_str[1:])
```

Output
https://v.redd.it/jvjih3f894b61/DASH_audio.mp4?source=fallback

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
s = "https://v.redd.it/jvjih3f894b61/DASH_1080.mp4?source=fallback"
re.sub(r"(?<=_).+?(?=\.)", "audio", s)
# 'https://v.redd.it/jvjih3f894b61/DASH_audio.mp4?source=fallback'
```

The two parenthesized expressions are positive lookahead/lookbehind assertions.

```
(?<=_).+?(?=\.)
```

non-greedily matches anything (`".+?"`) between `"_"` and `"."`.